# HTML font size 62.5% - how to calculate line-height?

Tags: css, scss-mixins

This is the case:

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
body { font-size: 16px; }
```

Now, according to the design the line-height should be `64px`, but I want to use `em` instead of `px`. Is there a formula to get px into em's? In this case: 64px would be 1.35em)? even better - is there a scss mixin for that?

Hope I'm making myself clear here... :)

Comment: This has a few handy mixins, one specifically for Font Sizing you might appreciate. https://github.com/csswizardry/frcss/blob/master/_tools.mixins.scss

Comment: line height is NOT the same as font size.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying...
Why not use `line-height: 4;` since `16*4=64` pixels. If you want it in `em` you can since you know the ratio of font-size to line-height. Remember line-height can be a factor of the computed font-size (which we use here) or a hard coded value.

em value changes depending on the parent elements and that's why people use it for responsive website design.

You can use PixelsToEm (http://pxtoem.com/) to convert pixel values to em values by providing the body font-size.

So your CSS may look like this:

```
body {
    font-size: 1em; /* equivalent to 16px (default font-size for browsers) */
    line-height: 4; /* equivalent to 64px */
}
```

Comment: { line-height: 4 } where? I'm not sure you got me there. I'm probably not clear enough but I did my best here :)